# Selecionar somente o primeiro registro de uma coluna

Tags: mysql, sql

O select abaixo retorna algo do tipo

```
005-A Produto A 21/AGOSTO
005-A Produto A 20/AGOSTO
005-A Produto A 21/MAIO
005-B Produto B 21/AGOSTO
```

e eu gostaria de um registro por produto igual ao seguinte

```
005-A Produto A 21/AGOSTO
005-B Produto B 21/AGOSTO
```

O que preciso para adaptar o seguinte select ?

```
select i.referencia, i.nome, nf.data_emissao
        from notas_fiscais_itens nfi 
        inner join notas_fiscais nf on nf.id = nfi.nota_fiscal_id 
        inner join itens i on i.id = nfi.item_id                
        order by i.referencia, nf.data_emissao desc
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Faltou você usar o GROUP BY + campo.

```
select i.referencia, i.nome, nf.data_emissao
    from notas_fiscais_itens nfi 
    inner join notas_fiscais nf on nf.id = nfi.nota_fiscal_id 
    inner join itens i on i.id = nfi.item_id                
    GROUP BY i.referencia, nf.data_emissao desc
```

Answer (score 1):

O registro A aparece 3x em seu exemplo. A única diferença entre eles é a Data.

Pelo o que você deseja, deve-se retornar o Produto com a Data mais recente. Sendo assim, é preciso utilizar um Group By aplicando a função agregadora MAX.

Algo assim:

```
select i.referencia, i.nome, max(nf.data_emissao)
        from notas_fiscais_itens nfi 
        inner join notas_fiscais nf on nf.id = nfi.nota_fiscal_id 
        inner join itens i on i.id = nfi.item_id                
        order by i.referencia, nf.data_emissao desc
group by i.referencia, i.nome
```